# $\mu_n\rightharpoonup\mu\implies|\mu_n-\mu|\rightharpoonup 0$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\mu_n,\mu\in P(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be probability measures. I am interested in understanding whether $\mu_n\rightharpoonup\mu$ (weak or narrow convergence) implies that $|\mu_n-\mu|\rightharpoonup 0$ where $|\nu|(A)=\sup\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}|\nu(A_i)|$ and the sup is taken over all partitions $A=\bigcup\limits_{i=0}^{\infty}A_i$  (total variation). So I have to show that for any $f\in C_b(\mathbb{R}^d)$, we have $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} fd|\mu_n-\mu|=0$ but because the definition of total variation is a bit peculiar, I am not sure how to start. We know that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}fd\mu_n\to \int_{\mathbb{R}}fd\mu$ but how to use this?

Comment: Consider the "Riemann sum": Let $\mu_n$ have mass $1/n$ at each of $n$ equally spaced points in $[0,1]$, and let $\mu$ be Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. To see this, let $x_n$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that $x_n \neq x$ for all $n$, but $x_n \to x$. Then the Dirac masses satisfy $\delta_{x_n} \to \delta_x$ weakly. However, you can show that for all $n$ we have $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}1 d|\delta_{x_n} - \delta_{x}| = |\delta_{x_n} - \delta_x|(\mathbb{R}^d) = 2$$ implying that $|\delta_{x_n} - \delta_x| \not\to 0$ weakly.

Comment: Thank you. $|\delta_{x_n}-\delta_x|$ is a measure according to my definition. I didn't understand how it can be equal to the real number 2.

Comment: I've edited my answer for more clarity.

Comment: I understand that $|\delta_{x_n}-\delta_x|(\mathbb{R}^d)=2$ because if $x_n\neq x$ then $\forall n$ we can find a set $A$ such that $x_n\in A$ and $x\notin A$ so $|(\delta_{x_n}-\delta_x)(A)|=1$ and $|(\delta_{x_n}-\delta_x)(\mathbb{R}^d\setminus A)|=1$ and so $|\delta_{x_n}-\delta_x|\ge 2$ and for any partition the sum will be smaller than $2$. However, why $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}1d|\delta_{x_n}-\delta_x|=|\delta_{x_n}-\delta_x|(\mathbb{R}^d)$?

Comment: For any measure $\mu$, $\mu (A) = \int \chi_A d \mu = \int_A 1 d\mu$.